# Find USB device's directory /sys/bus/usb/devices/ using idVendor/idProduct

Tags: usb, bash, scripts, directory

I'm trying to make a script that takes the product and vendor id printed by using `lsusb`, then checking against this ID to find the USB device's directory in `/sys/bus/usb/devices`.

I initially thought the Bus and Device number printed by lsusb would point to the appropriate folder.  For example, if `Bus = 002` and `Device = 002`, the USB's directory would be `/usb/devices/2-2`.  Unfortunately, this turned out to not be the case.

I can manually find the appropriate folder using this command I found in another thread:

```
for X in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*; do 
    echo "$X"
    cat "$X/idVendor" 2>/dev/null 
    cat "$X/idProduct" 2>/dev/null
    echo
done
```

However, I need a script that can automate finding this folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question, the following script should do the job:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ];then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` idVendor idProduct"
  exit 1
fi


for X in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*; do 
    if [ "$1" == "$(cat "$X/idVendor" 2>/dev/null)" -a "$2" == "$(cat "$X/idProduct" 2>/dev/null)" ]
    then
        echo "$X"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this a little simpler:

```
rgrep -l $1 /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idVendor | sed 's/\(.*\)\/idVendor/\1/' | xargs -iXXX rgrep -l $2 XXX/idProduct | sed 's/\(.*\)\/idProduct/\1/'
```

You may want to keep the sanity check though if you want to save this as a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ];then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` idVendor idProduct"
  exit 1
fi

rgrep -l ^${1}$ /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idVendor | sed 's/\(.*\)\/idVendor/\1/' | xargs -iXXX rgrep -l ^${2}$ XXX/idProduct | sed 's/\(.*\)\/idProduct/\1/'
```