# Disable automount of a specific mtp device?

Tags: 16.04, mount, nautilus, automount, mtp

On a Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop, I have a phone that is mounted using MTP as soon as I plug it in. I don't want this to happen, I actually just want it to charge off my computer's USB power. When I plug other devices in, I do want them to automount so I only want to stop the default action for this specific device.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

First, find the VendorID and ProductID of the device using `lsusb`. For my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, the appropriate line is below.

```
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
---------------VendorID--^ : ^--ProductID
```

You also need the directory associated with where this device is plugged in. You can go hunting around `/sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idProduct` manually, or you can use [this quick little script](https://askubuntu.com/a/350016/47461) by @radu-rădeanu.

Save this to ~/bin/findUSBbyID.sh and `chmod +x` it.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ];then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` idVendor idProduct"
  exit 1
fi


for X in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*; do 
    if [ "$1" == "$(cat "$X/idVendor" 2>/dev/null)" -a "$2" == "$(cat "$X/idProduct" 2>/dev/null)" ]
    then
        echo "$X"
    fi
done
```

Run it as `~/bin/findUSBbyID.sh 04e8 6860`. The output will look somthing like this:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2
```

With this information you want to create a new file called `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-disable-usb-device.rules`. You'll need root permissions so `sudo` or `gksudo` your favorite editor as appropriate.

The file should contain one line like below. Correct the VendorID and ProductID to match your device. Also correct the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/$something/authorized` path to match your product as found with the findUSBbyID.sh script.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2/authorized'"
```

You may get another popup "Unable to mount an MTP device". That issue is [being discussed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624183/how-can-i-stop-unable-to-mount-android-device-messages-from-popping-up).